# How can I use an Epson Stylus C64 printer?

Tags: hardware, drivers, usb, printing

The Epson Stylus C64 is a USB printer. How can I install this so that I can print documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was plug in the USB cable. This has to be the cable that connects to the printer, not some other random cable. Yes, I plugged in the wrong thing :P

When I plugged it in, I got a notification telling me that the printer had been added. I could then select this printer from the print dialog.

[image]